# Connection to sup2.2

Tags: sybase, sup

I am developing an IOS application, and I need to develop connection interface ( user, password). Pressing the connect button I must synchronize with sup2.2 .I followed many tutorials but I still couldn't connect to server sup2.2

Answer (score 0):

There are tutorials available that will guide u step by step.

Follow this on Sybase Infocentre.
[Tutorial for iOS object API application development](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01213.0222/doc/html/title.html)

Also, if you can specify where exactly you are getting stuck or what your error is, it will help resolve your problem.